# Incompatibility between mathspec and url packages

Tags: xetex, typewriter, mathspec, url

I use xelatex and `mathspec`'s `\setmathfont(Digits,Latin,Greek)` which works just fine and the `url` package with the Computer Modern Unicode Typewriter fonts. What happens is that all digits in my URLs appear in text font instead of typewriter font:

[image: Incorrect digits in URL]

When I remove the `\setmathfont` command then the URL comes out perfectly:

[image: Correct digits in URL]

At the demand of Ulrike, here is a full example (I hate Arial and used it only because it is a widely available font). For the `cmuntt` font you will need to change the location on disk:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathspec,xltxtra,url}
\setmainfont{Arial}
\setmathfont(Digits,Latin,Greek){Arial}
\setmonofont{cmuntt}[
    Path           = /somewhere/,
    Extension      = .ttf,
    UprightFont={cmuntt},
    ItalicFont={cmunti},
    BoldFont={cmuntb},
    BoldItalicFont={cmuntx}
]
\def\UrlFont{\ttfamily}
\begin{document}
Test URL: \url{http://www.1234.com}

Test math: $x^2+y^2=z^2$.
\end{document}
```

And here is the result of the small test file, as you can see the digits in the URL are in Arial and not in Computer Modern Unicode Typewriter:

[image]

How can I tell `mathspec` not to interfere with URLs from the `url` package?

Comment: url uses math so packages changing the math setup affects it. Make a complete example for a test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this could work (I don't have cmuntt and not the time to search it):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathspec}
\usepackage{url}

\def\UrlFont{\ttfamily}
\setmathfont(Digits,Greek,Latin)[Numbers=Lining]{Arial}
\makeatletter
\DeclareMathVersion{url}
\SetSymbolFont{\eu@DigitsArabic@symfont}{url}{TU}{\ttdefault}{m}{n}
\makeatother
\def\UrlFont{\ttfamily\mathversion{url}}  
\begin{document}
$a=123$

\url{www.abc123.de}

$a=123$

\end{document}
```

[image]